# Xcode GIT problems iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, google-maps-api-3, git-checkout

So I made a repository for an app and everything in Xcode is setup. Now another person tries to pull it and that works fine until this message appears: `The File "UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate" could not be unlocked, unlocking failed for an unknown reason`.

The project uses the Google Maps API and gives the error: `"GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" file not found`. Even though the project is a direct clone, it works for me but not for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the error of `"GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"` file not found.

You may have not set the path properly. For setting right path do following steps:

- Go to Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
- Click on + option
- Select the GoogleMaps Framework. If you have added it from outside than go there & select it.
- Go to Targets -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths
- Remove the older path of Google Maps API from it (keep new path don't remove it)

For "The File "UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate" could not be unlocked" issue

refer this : http://www.meetup.com/818-iOS-Developers/messages/boards/thread/20469352

Answer (score 1):

You probably corrupted the file by using Git, that, or you overwrote a locally saved file with something from the cloud. Try recreating the project without using Git, and see if it works.